# how to fix Commit to git failed due to network

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, bitbucket

I added files to git git->add in android studio, files were added successfully. When I pressed commit and push, it was interrupted due to network issue. And nothing was pushed to git.

Now When I'm trying to add and commit, it ways nothing to push.

Kindly advise how to fix this in android studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in the repository if it is already pushed, if not, try using `git log` and get that particular `commit`, `cherry pick` that commit in a new branch and push it again. You would be good to go.

Comment: I checked already in repository, it was not pushed. is there any way it can be pushed to existing branch, which it had pushed earlier

Comment: Almost git operations happen locally except pull/push. Checkout to the branch that you are working on, use git status to check if there is any untracked file, commit (if needed), then push to origin again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files already committed in your local system. Thats why you are unable to see any files when committing again.

To push the committed code, Goto `VCS -> Git -> Push`, You will see all the committed files, So you can push it to repository.

**Alternative Terminal way,**
You can also execute this command in terminal to push your code to `master`

`git push -u origin master`

Hope this helps.